# Text on multiple line before big curly brackets

Tags: equations, cases

[image: what I want]
Is there any way to write a multiple line equations like this one?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

[image]

```
\[  
\begin{aligned}[c]
x &: \\
y &: \\
z &:
\end{aligned}  
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}[c]
T+qh     &= 0 \\
-P_1-P_2 &= 0 \\
M_z-2ql  &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{cases} 
\]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make two matrices and use the `\left...\middle...\right` notation with the open brace as the `\middle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\left.\begin{matrix}x:\\y:\\z:\end{matrix}\middle\{\begin{matrix*}[r]T+qh=0\\-P_1-P_2=0\\M_z-2ql=0\end{matrix*}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```